# gnome shell + external monitor = garbage (ubuntu 11.10 on eeepc)

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, eeepc

i'm using gnome shell on an asus eeepc (atom N570, 1Gb ram, opengl renderer mesa DRI intel IGD). As soon as i connect my external monitor, i get garbage on both screens. When i disconnect, the display goes back to normal.

I think i had kind of similar issues with unity 3D, where i got a message telling me that the resolution for the extended screen exceded the maximum one supported by my hardware. In that case i could choose to lower the resolution, clone the displays, turn of the eeepc's one. Here i seem not to have control at all, since the switch happens when i connect the cable.

What can i do? Is there a solution (which doesn't involve dropping gnome shell)? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have eeepc 1005ha, with intel onboard video.
I used GNOME3 before last update. Now I can`t switch on it. I do not like Unity on some reasons, and 3d is to slow for my netbook, so I can use only Unity 2d or GNOME Classic.

Our Netbooks can`t support resolution more than 2048x1024 in normal rendering speed. And second monitor - is like sum of both.

Comment: how do I use 2D with gnome shell? Or maybe you are referring to Unity 2D?

Comment: yep, in fact i would be happy to just turn off the eeepc screen and just use the external one with a resolution lower than the maximum one, as I do with unity 3D. But on gnome shell i can't because as soon as i plug the cable to the netbook's vga output, the screen is automatically extended. It would be better if it did nothing and let me choose what to do from System Settings -> Monitor. I found shell to be very comfortable and "snappier" than unity on my eeepc, so it would be a pity to give up using it because of such a marginal thing :/

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem on a dual core desktop with intel graphics as well.  I think this problem has to do with running two screen with two different resolutions.  If I clone my monitors all is fine, and if I setup the two monitors with the same resolution things work ok.  My monitors are different sizes, and when I set it to display at the right resolution for each monitor all I get is garbage until I unplug one monitor.  It does it in Unity 3d as well as 2d.  Everything worked perfect in 11.10 and 11.04.  If anyone out there has dual monitors working with two different resolutions on 12.04 I'd love to hear it.

Comment: i would love to just clone the screen, but the screen extension is automatic and it doesn't let me to choose anything but staring at the digital "pollock" screen. I'm going to upgrade to 12.04 and see if things get better there.